# filemtime() показывает не корректную дату

Tags: php, ubuntu, сервер

при использовании filemtime,fileatime или filectime показывают дату 1970-01-01 03:00:00 для файлов, однако времена изменения папок показывает правильно

```php
$files = scandir($dir);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
    if(!file_exists($files[$i]."/.lock")){
    $result .= '<tr>'.
        '<td><a href="out/AA">'.str_replace("AA", "/${_POST['pass']}/".$files[$i], "<a href=\"out/AA\">").$files[$i].'</a></td>'.
        '<td>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($files[$i])).'</td>';
        echo "<script> alert($filemtime($files[$i]))</script>"
        ;#'<td><a href="out/AA">'.str_replace("AA", $files[$i], "<a href=\"out/AA\">").$files[$i].'</a></td>'.

        '</tr>';
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие ваши доказательства?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Доказательства чего?

Comment: Видимо, того, что в mtime/atime/ctime записано что-то отличное от 1970 года. Если в них и правда записан именно 1970 год, значит дата показывается корректная

Comment: Для того чтобы функция работала с файлом, нужно передавать в неё не только имя файла, но (лучше) и полный путь для него, либо относительный (т.е. используя $dir переменную)